# How do you instantiate an Excel VBA AddIn variable

Tags: excel, vba

In the references window, you can browse to and set a reference to a custom AddIn. For purposes of discussion let's say it is named MyAddIn.xlam. I changed the project name to MyAddIn and it resides in the standard AddIns path. So I have successfully done that and then have defined an associated global variable as below in a different Excel workbook:

```
Private m_MyAddIn As MyAddIn.thisworkbook
```

How and when do I instantiate the variable I have defined? It would be simple if I could cast the associated Application.AddIns collection item to my specific AddIn but that isn't an option.

Within the MyAddIn code, I have tried defining a public property ParentWorkbook that just returns ThisWorkbook. I have also tried doing the same in a public class defined in MyAddIn. But I cannot figure out how to instantiate the variable.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. MyAddIn raises a custom event MyEvent whenever a Workbook is opened or a new sheet is created
2. One or more custom xlsbs MyCustom1.xlsb, MyCustom2.xlsb will handle the event
3. Because the xlsbs are looking for an event, I need to be able to define a  WithEvents MyAddIn variable in the xlsbs to be able to handle them
4. So for example, a PivotTable xlsb might do some custom actions based on PivotTable events. These could all be setup in the xlsb once it received notifications that a new file was opened. It could check to see if a PivotTable was present and skip all others, etc.

Why am I trying to do it this way?

1. I'm trying to avoid a bunch of chatter. If each xlsb uses the application object to check for open files, etc. they will all run every time a file is opened in Excel
2. My thought is that only MyAddIn will check that event and then raise the custom events as appropriate so the xlsbs.

I hope this helps.

Thanks for any ideas and/or suggestions.

Comment: add some code or explain what you reaaly want to do because that's as clear as a cappuccino for me 8-|

Comment: Any add-in is a workbook... So, declare it as `Dim m_MyAddIn As Workbook` then set it as `Set m_MyAddIn = Workbooks("AddinName.xlam")`. After that, you can use any property, methods exposed by the add-in in discussion. You can try `Debug.print m_MyAddIn.Sheets.Count`, for instance... Or public variables exposed by it. In order to  run its methods, you should proceed in a different way. The simplest is to add a reference to it, in the workbook you try setting. You can do it without  a reference, but it would be good to better explain what you want accomplishing...

Comment: If you need to "read some information" written in its sheets, you can use the above suggested way. If you want `reading' something else, you should better explain what that means...

Comment: Thanks for the quick and timely comments. I have added additional information in the question.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Did my recent changes help?

Comment: I see most of your questions do not have an accepted answer. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should trap App level Workbook.Activate events like explained here: https://www.exceltip.com/events-in-vba/how-to-create-application-level-events-in-excel-vba.html

Main points from that page:

- Insert a class module. Name it as you want. I named it MyAppEvents.
- Define an event variable of Application type with keyword WithEvents.
- Initialize this event in class_initialize() subroutine.
- Now define the events you want to use. From the top-left drop-down, select the event object.

You can then `set wb = ActiveWorkbook` and do what you want with it.